# UIScroll View which contains UIScrollView (Images)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I build a UIScrollView which is allowed to scroll right and left, in this main UIScrollView I added custom UIViews, each UIView contains an UIImageView with UIScrollView, and this UIScrollView can only pinch, the problem is that the main UIScrollView works fine, but the one in the custom UIView don't work.

I tried to disable the main scrollView and try scrolling in the scrollview of the UIView and it does not work.

should I make sure of enabling disabling something, what cause this, and if I'm using of multiple UIscrollViews or nested scrollViews what should I take care of?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Try to handle the touch events of Custom Subviews. In Your Custom Subview handle the events:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event{}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event{}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event{}
```

Comment: this methods are not being called in the UIScrollView of the inner UIView

Comment: I get everytime I start pinching this error: Ignoring call to [UIPanGestureRecognizer setTranslation:inView:] since gesture recognizer is not active.

Comment: then implement these methods to handle event (do NSLoging to check that the subViews are responding)

Comment: I check I didn't get responds, I do NSlog in each one and get nothin

Comment: yes that what I have done, I applied this on the custom UIView, I don't get respond and also on the main UIsrolllView I don't get respond

Comment: @user784625 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1865/discussion-between-makboney-and-user784625)

Answer (score 0):

```
    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scale:)];
    pinchRecognizer.delegate = (id) self;
    [scrollView addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];
```

I solve the issue by adding gesture